# Using the Printers Unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe7, printers

I want to access the Printers Unit in Delphi XE7. I am not able to do this, because „the Printers Unit cannot be resolved“ as shown on this image:

[image]

As a beginner in Delphi, I don’t know what to do. Don’t judge me. Is there a way of adding a reference or something?
Thank you.

Comment: The red squiggly line is from error insight, a functionality that doesn't work most of the time. Just deactivate this feature...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Delphi XE2, RTL/VCL/FMX unit names were updated with [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Unit_Scope_Names). So you have to either:

1. use fully qualified unit names in your `uses` clause, like `Vcl.Printers`.
2. go to `Project Options` -> `Delphi Compiler` -> `Unit scope names` and make sure `Vcl` is listed, then you can use just `Printers` in your `uses` clause.

A new `Vcl` project has the following default Unit Scope Names:

```
Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;Vcl;Vcl.Imaging;Vcl.Touch;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Shell`
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: I kinda hate this whole Namespace idea in Delphi, i like it the old school way.

Comment: @user1803300 Since the introduction of Firemonkey, namespaces were kinda inevitable.